# VBA Regex unable to read the string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a VBA macro, which is able to find the below possibility of strings.

```
With mainSel.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[\{\[][a-zA-Z0-9\,\.\:\-;^l^13 ]@[\}\]]"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
```

- {xxxxx}
- { xxxx }
- {xxx }
- {xxxx, xxxx}
- { xxxx,xxxx}
- {xxxx,xxxx }
- { xxxx, xxxx }

But the current situation is, when it finds a field code in the document, it skips the all other occurrence of the matches. If I remove the space in the regular expression above it is processing the string after the fieldcode but it is skipping the strings which is having space in it like { xxxx}.

EX: this is an example {xxxx} -getting processed.this is the [fieldcode]. this is the string{xxx} which is not getting processed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop over occurences, since [`Execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977.aspx) returns `True` if the find operation is successful:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFind()
    Dim Content As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set Content = ActiveDocument.Content
    ' let's print what we got so far
    Debug.Print "All text is:" & vbNewLine & Content.Text

    With Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        ' our find loop
        Debug.Print "Occurences: "
        While .Execute(MatchWildcards:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop, FindText:="[\{\[][a-zA-Z0-9\,\.\:\-;^l^13 ]@[\}\]]")
            ' count occurences
            i = i + 1
            ' lets bold text just for testing purposes
            Content.Bold = True
            ' and also print each occurence
            Debug.Print vbTab & "Occurence #" & i & vbTab & Content.Text
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

```
All text is:
{xxxxx} 
asdasd
{ xxxx } 
As{asd}
asff
{xxx } 
{xxxx, xxxx} 
safasf
{ xxxx,xxxx} 
{xxxx,xxxx } 
{ xxxx, xxxx }


Occurences: 
    Occurence #1    {xxxxx}
    Occurence #2    { xxxx }
    Occurence #3    {asd}
    Occurence #4    {xxx }
    Occurence #5    {xxxx, xxxx}
    Occurence #6    { xxxx,xxxx}
    Occurence #7    {xxxx,xxxx }
    Occurence #8    { xxxx, xxxx }
```

Also, this isn't a regex at all and thoose patterns are really crude. If you need a real regex, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you help... but in the text we have a field code between the required strings... once it find the field code it is not reading the next occurence. 
For Example:
All text is:
{xxxxx}  [field code] asdasd { xxxx } As{asd} asff {xxx } {xxxx, xxxx} safasf
{ xxxx,xxxx} {xxxx,xxxx } { xxxx, xxxx }

In this situation it only reads the first occurence. i have tried the provided solution and it gives the below output:
Occurences: 
    Occurence #1    {xxxxx}
    Occurence #2    
    Occurence #3    
 .
 .
 .
 .
 infinite

Comment: @Rocky, it's works for me with your "all text". I [got 9 occurences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XyIO.png) (your field code catched too), so I assume that it's what you desire, isn't it? Unfortunately, I don't familiar with those patterns.

Comment: @Rocky, also, I suggest you to drop those ugly patterns too and use a RegEx instead! There're a lot of sites like regex101.com where you can paste a lot more of data and test patterns on-line. I'm sure, pattern for rule "grab all inside curly braces with them and if there're square braces after that - grab them too with same fashion" much more easier and more readable, if I understand your rule right. So try it with real data and if you stuck again - update your question with link to regex101. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for you help.. now i am using the below regex . but i need to loop through each and ever matches and replace the string if needed.. could you please help..

`Sub sampleregex()

Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "[\{\[][A-z0-9\s\.\,\:\;]*[\]\}]"
regEx.Global = True
Dim match As Object
Dim Content As Range
Set Content = ActiveDocument.Content

Dim matches As MatchCollection
Set matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)
For Each match In matches
Debug.Print vbTab & "Occurence #" & vbTab & match
[matched string = "newstring"]
Next match
End Sub`